# Cilium Ingress Controller gRPC Web Stream Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web, cilium

I want to create a web application, which streams a gRPC backend. To make gRPC web work i need an envoy proxy which translate HTTP/1 to HTTP/2 and back. Can i achieve that with the cilium ingress controller in Kubernetes?

I already tested gRPC web with this example (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/echo)

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to implement that with either Cilium Ingress or even Cilium Gateway API.